# O que são os pacotes?

Tags: java, apache-cordova

Estou começando com o Phonegap e ao criar um projeto tem a seguinte estrutura:

```
phonegap create helloWorld com.dominio.pasta HelloWorld
```

Mas nunca entendi sobre esse pacote. É uma URL ao contrário? Para que serve? Alguém pode me explicar?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O pacote nada mais é do que uma forma de se definir qual entidade é a dona do código e organizar o código em grupos lógicos dentro desta entidade.

Porque? Principalmente para evitar colisões de nome. Vamos supor que as organizações Tabajara criaram uma classe chamada `Pessoa` para os projetos deles. Por outro lado, a organização XPTO também criou uma classe `Pessoa` de uma forma e para uma finalidade completamente diferente para uso deles. Depois disso, o Pedro precisa utilizar no projeto dele as classes criadas pelas organizações Tabajara e pela XPTO, mas isso causaria um problema, pois haveriam duas classes chamadas `Pessoa`.

A solução para isso seria usar o pacote. As organizações Tabajara poderiam chamar a classes deles de `org.tabajara.Pessoa` e a XPTO de `br.com.xpto.Pessoa`.

Mas porque basear-se no nome do domínio? Porque em geral, o domínio só pode ter um único dono, e portanto, se você é o dono do domínio `xpto.com.br`, ao utilizar `br.com.xpto` então você terá uma certa garantia de que ninguém estará colidindo nomes com você. Por outro lado, se você usasse apenas `xpto` como nome de pacote, pode ser que a XPTO da China inventasse de usar `xpto` também, ao invés de `cn.com.xpto`.

Porque o nome do domínio é reverso? Por causa da estrutura de hierarquia. Vamos supor que você seja dono do domínio `xpto.com.br`, e na sua empresa você tenha vários projetos. Você tem o projeto da loja virtual, do cadastro de clientes, e da emissão de arquivos de contabilidade. Dentro da loja virtual, vamos supor que você tenha um módulo de persistência de dados, um de processamento de pagamentos e um de serviços web.

Se você definir o pacote de todos eles como apenas `xpto.com.br`, o resultado vai ser uma bagunça, então você vai querer usar uma hierarquia como `xpto.com.br/loja/persistencia`, `xpto.com.br/loja/web`,  `xpto.com.br/loja/pagamentos`, `xpto.com.br/cadastroclientes`. Essa estrutura de hierarquia segue o mesmo modelo em que as pastas do seu computador são modeladas, o que não funcionaria se as suas pastas fossem `persistencia/loja/xpto/com/br` por exemplo. O que acontece é que `persistencia` é um módulo de `loja` que é um módulo de `xpto.com.br`. Entretanto, o próprio nome do domínio também é hierárquico, mas está ao contrário, então seguindo com essa tendência temos, `br/com/xpto/loja/persistencia`.

Um fato que reforça essa ideia de colocar o domínio ao contrário, é que em muitos lugares, há subdomínios dentro de um mesmo domínio cuja hierarquia é equivalente à hierarquia de pastas. Por exemplo, eu poderia usar `loja.xpto.com.br` ou `xpto.com.br/loja`, mas em ambos os casos `loja` está dentro de `xpto.com.br`, e para manter uma consistência e seguir o modelo de pastas hierárquicas, inverte-se o domínio e ambos resultam em `br/com/xpto/loja/persistencia`.

Para falar a verdade, quem foi definido na ordem inversa, não é o pacote, e sim o domínio. Ao desinverter-se o domínio, retorna-se a ordem normal.

Por fim, há um pequeno porém. Esse esquema funciona em cima da presunção de que o domínio utilizado é seu. Esse esquema quebra quando o domínio utilizado não é seu, ou quando o seu domínio é alterado, então cuidado com essas circunstâncias.

Comment: +1. Muito boa resposta. Escreveu tudo o que eu estava escrevendo e mais coisa..

Comment: Cara, super explicado. Muito obrigado!